# Forecast multiple features in Time Series Data (using key)

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have a data set of multiple users activity for the last 2 years. 
My problem is to forecast for a given person is likely to do what kind of activity in the near future.

For example:

```
Today is 2019-05-27 
Input should be user_id (ex: 1)
```

Then it has to produce something like below:

- User with user_id 1 is likely to climb a mountain on 2019-05-30
- User with user_id 1 is likely to go to trip on 2019-06-02

All this should be forecasted using users activity history. (Frequency of each activity can be different)

How do solve this problem using machine learning on python?

What algorithm is best for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

any (time series analysis) tsa algorithm will work for your problem statement but first

**1.** you need to clean the data & bring it in the format that algorithm can learn from.

**2.** you can create a pandas dataframe having two or more columns, first will be the index having all the dates,time & second column will have a vector/number which represents the activities from your dataset from third column onwards you can keep values for different users in different column

`|---------------------|------------------|
|      index          |   data_user1     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      date           |   activity_label |
|---------------------|------------------|`

**3.** For converting your activity to a vector/number you can use label encoder

**4.** Impute the missing timestamps in your dataset.

**5.** Use any tsa algorithm either sliding window approach with LSTM/NN or the pre-implemented algos from statsmodels.tsa

I'll suggest you to use ARIMA/SARIMA, if you have date in the right form it's as simple as writing just these 3 lines.

```
model=statsmodels.api.tsa.SARIMAX(train_df,order=(1,0,1),seasonal_order=(1,1,0,24))
model = model.fit()
model.predict()
```